# What's an easy approach to provide Wi-Fi/Webserver to mobile phone apps without hotspot

Tags: embedded, wifi, mobile

I'm a software programmer and I'm up to start a project of an embedded outdoor device which I will be able to control by any mobile phone.

My preferred approach is having the embedded device provide a HTTP webserver via Wi-Fi, so I wouldn't be required to create different apps for different phones.

What's the most easy way to add such Wi-Fi/HTTP support to a microcontroller? I guess the embedded device will have to provide a hotspot by itself so the phone can connect to it. But I'm not sure about this. Perhaps there are more easy ways?

Bluetooth doesn't seem appropriate here because of its limited reach.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi with WiFi dongle springs to mind.

Comment: As far as range goes, unless you're doing 802.11n, Wi-Fi has about the same range as Bluetooth or BLE -- all about 100 m outdoors, less inside.  802.11n is at least double that.

Comment: Wait, isn't Bluetooth 2.1 edr like 30 feet in most cases? b/g Wifi is always a better choice in distance and thru put

Comment: @Majenko: I see... I never worked with RP before. Will it allow for easy, time critical serial I/O? I worry that the OS with its interrupts will render it difficult to address the I/O functions easily.
@trco/@passerby: The limited reach of Bluetooth is my current knowledge, too.

Comment: OK, I just read the [specs](http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Basics.aspx). Class 1 Bluetooth devices can span 100m. But which class would a standard mobile phone have implemented?

Comment: Have you thought about a GSM modem? Or a cell phone with a microcontroller? The cell provides either a Hotspot,  or via a cell service

Comment: @AxD Serial is slow compared to the speed of the board.  For really critical timing work, though, you could always strap on an external MCU as a dedicated IO processor - the chipKIT Pi might be ideal for that.

Comment: Most consumer devices are class 2, 10 meters.

Comment: Just finished a project very similar on a ti msp430.  They also make a wifi module the cc3200 that supports ap mode so your phone could connect and has embedded stack.  Think it's a slow arm on the inside.  Wasn't too hard to add a simple http server to send commands and get feedback.

Comment: @Passerby Yes, you're right about the reduced range -- I was automatically thinking of BT Class 1 because that's what the company I am contracting at uses for all their medical wireless products.  Spoiled I guess.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy: Your solutions sounds rather intriguing. Do you perhaps know of some ready-to-use board, with everything hardware related already in place?

Comment: Maybe this dev kit for it?  http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-cc3200-launchxl.html. Haven't used it myself but it looked interesting

Comment: I think I'm going to go for the TI CC3200 approach. This chip contains both a Wi-Fi component and an MCU which I can use to create my PWM output.

The Raspberry Pi approach (in addition to any Wi-Fi addition, like a dongle or other Wi-Fi module) seems too big for my needs. I don't need HDMI, HQ-Audio etc. Along with the OS they'd just be unnecessary load to me.

Unfortunately @SomeHardwareGuy didn't give his suggestion as an answer yet. Otherwise I'd mark is as my answer.

Thanks to all who have been trying to help!

Comment: There's also the Arduino Yun http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun. AP mode is supported, and the web server is already provided out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try the TI wifi module, the CC3200, it supports ap mode so your phone could connect and has embedded stack. I think it's a slow arm on the inside. It wasn't too hard to add a simple http server to send commands and get feedback on the MSP430 so this should have more than enough power to do it.

It looks like the eval board comes with an HTTP server already in flash among other things.  I looked at their downloadable SDK and it lists "http server" as one of the examples.

Here's their eval board: the [CC3200-LAUNCHXL](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpads-connected-cc3200-launchxl.html)

[image]

Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

This (or something similar) seems to be what you're looking for: http://www.connectone.com/?p=1
It has a WiFi-LAN bridge (so you can connect it to a router via LAN), an embedded web server and provides access via USB, SPI or UART for your microcontroller (or, in the case of USB, something like the RaspberryPi) to take control.

Comment: After browsing through the documentation I'm not sure whether I can directly attach the WiFi module to something like the Raspberry Pi. Wouldn't it drastically increase costs to always buy an evaluation board?

Comment: If by "evaluation board" you meant the RaspberryPi, you could of course use a microcontroller via the UART or SPI interface. The product I linked is available as a chip as well. Obviously using the eval board would increase cost, yes. If you plan to produce high volumes of the product and don't have electronic design skills yourself, I would recommend hiring an additional person to handle the electronics development, but to get a prototype up and running, an evaluation board is probably the best solution.

Comment: Also mind that even if you plan the prototype with an evalutation board, you still have the possibility to switch to a self-designed PCB (with the microcontroller on it as well) later on.

Answer (score 0):

How about [SparkCore](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sparkdevices/spark-core-wi-fi-for-everything-arduino-compatible) ? Arduino Compatible & Plug n Play.